# How to real-time sync local Postgres instance to Cloud Postgres

Tags: postgresql, cloud, replication

I have a local postgres database (9.2) running on Ubuntu that is constantly being written to by an application capturing sub-second data. (99.9% of the transactions are inserts).  I also have a postgres database with the same data structure sitting in the cloud.  I need a way to get some of the data (not all of the data) up the cloud in near real-time. (Oh, I might have several local postgres databases pushing to the same cloud database.) I would of course need to ensure all the data I want gets delivered if the connection went down. Ideally I would just like to specify what tables/views to push. Anyone have any ideas?  I would prefer not to have to write my own solution but I am not taking any option off the table.

I have looked at postgres streaming replication, however, from what I have read it's a full database replication not just a subset of the data.

Thanks in advance for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Londiste, Bucardo or Slony-I can do this.

See [Replication, Clustering and Connection Pooling](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) on the PostgreSQL wiki for details.

Londiste would probably be my first choice for this use case, mainly for simplicity.

Comment: Have you ever used SymmetricDS?  After reading the link you provided it looks like it was designed for low bandwidh connections and even periods of network outages.  It also looks like there is a way to have it read the configurations from a central server. If I am reading it correctly it might be able to sync data directly from postgress to MS SQL Server.  Thoughts?

Comment: @hewstone I haven't used it, so I can't comment.